# Wordpress Contact Form 7 does not display its content

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Until some time ago my form made with Contact Form 7 plugin seemed to work just fine. I had literally 0 problems with it.

Yesterday I have made a quick check and there it is. My form does not show its content, displays only the [shortcode]. As a matter of fact, all my forms behave in the same manner. The content is there because I can see it while I am in the divi editor. Therefore I tried relinking it and saving changes to forms, pages... It did not help. Still, when I am out of the edit mode or simply in the user view forms do not display the content.

I have easy updates manager set to automatically update other plugins, but none of them seem to interfere with the Contact Form 7. Also, I updated divi editor manually after noticing the problem and it changed nothing.

Comment: first check whether contact form7 is deactivated, if not for sure the problem is in your editor used in divi, it is not rendering the shortcodes

Comment: @charankumar If you mean whether my plugin is turned on then yes it is. Just to be sure everything works fine I turned it off and on again and it made no difference... The divi worked before just fine...

Comment: Where did you put your shortcode? In a template? In a page wysiwyg?

Comment: @Mtxz I opened Divi Creator and pasted it into the text: content where html is present, according to syntax rules.

Comment: If you have the choice between visual and text/HTML editor, put the shortcode in "visual" mode. You also can try to `echo do_shortcode('[your_short]');` in a template file to see if shortcode is valid.

Comment: @Mtxz Tried this and everything was ok, least supposed to be but then again still was not working. The problem was with another addon which updated on its own and posed compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually sorted out the problem by an accident. Turns out it was the compatibility issue with another plugin which updated on its own.
**Future tip** - be careful with auto-updater. Keep track of what is happening on the website and if there are any updates make sure they do not proceed unnoticed.

Look up to @charankumar and @Mtxz comments for which I am very grateful. These could solve the problem if it was based on faulty form implementation.